# Replacing elements between lists in python

Tags: python

I am currently trying to replace elements in a 2D list with elements in another list, so as to implement a game I am making in python. Here is what I have so far:

```
listA = [1, 3, 5]
listB = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

for a in range(len(listA)):
    alpha = (a/3) #number of rows in listB
    beta = (a/3) #number of columns in listB
    listB[alpha][beta] = 123
```

When I do this, I get

```
[[123, 123, 123], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

instead of what I want given the parameters,

```
[[0, 123, 0], [123, 0, 123], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you expect `(a/3)` to be? It'll never be anything else but 0..

Comment: Looping by index is always a bad idea in Python, instead, loop through and build up a new list - using a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) would be a good idea.

Comment: Actually, it'll only ever be zero...so your output is not possible!

Comment: Why are `[123, 123, 0]` and `[0, 123, 123]` excluded?  What rule is followed to produce your results?

Comment: There's no need to divide by three if you want indices

Comment: seems even strange that you manage to get THAT output, since your indexes will only be 0, and you'll be replacing the first element the whole loop

Comment: Are you wanting to use the values in `listA` for something?  Right now you're not using it at all.

Comment: so: 1,3,5 are the indexes where you want that 123 to be put in, and then you want the resulting listB to be split a list of lists? is that it?

Comment: alpha = a/3; beta = a%3

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo Yes, that's the case, would it be better to go through with list comprehension?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of iterating through the indices of listA using `for a in range(len(listA)):`, you should iterate through the elements of listA using `for a in listA:`

Assuming that the indices in A translate into coordinates in B like so:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Then beta, AKA the column of B corresponding to `a`, should be calculated as `a%3`, rather than `a/3`.

```
listA = [1, 3, 5]
listB = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

for a in listA:
    #two slashes is integer division, not a comment, 
    #despite markup's color scheme
    alpha = a//3 
    beta = a%3
    listB[alpha][beta] = 123

print listB
```

Output:

```
[[0, 123, 0], [123, 0, 123], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: I tried @Kevin 's suggestion in idle and it worked, thank you Kevin and everyone else who gave input!

Answer (score 3):

If you use `numpy` this is pretty easy:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1,3,5])
B = np.zeros((3,3))

B.flat[A] = 123

print B
```

out:

```
[[   0.  123.    0.]
 [ 123.    0.  123.]
 [   0.    0.    0.]]
```

Note that what `.flat` does is return a "flattened" version of your list:

```
[   0.  123.    0.  123.    0.  123.    0.    0.    0.]
```

Comment: Simpler even: `B.flat[A] = 123`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for a in range(len(listA)):
...     alpha = (listA[a]/3) #number of rows in listB
...     beta = (listA[a]%3) #number of columns in listB
...     listB[alpha][beta] = 123
... 
>>> listB
[[0, 123, 0], [123, 0, 123], [0, 0, 0]]
```

you must use the elements inside your listA, or it's pointles to use the indexes generated by range. Also, you should do a bit of math to properly fetch the row and column index

edit: I suggest you take a look at Kevin's answer and explanation, mine is just a quick correction of your code.

Comment: Better to iterate through `listA` than using `range` and then indexing `listA`, as in Kevin's answer.

Comment: yeah, was just correcting his initial code, Kevin's more pythonic and clear indeed

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> listA = [1, 3, 5]
>>> listB = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> listB_unwrapped = list(chain(*listB))
>>> for i in listA:
    listB_unwrapped[i] = 123


>>> listB = zip(*[iter(listB_unwrapped)]*3)
>>> listB
[(0, 123, 0), (123, 0, 123), (0, 0, 0)]
>>>
```